# Should I check for a MySQL connection with is_resource or mysqli_ping?

Tags: php, mysql, connection

Should I check for a MySQL connection with `is_resource` or `mysqli_ping`? Why?

```
if (!mysql_ping($mysqli)) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,
                         $db_username,
                         $db_password,
                         $db_name);
}

if (!is_resource($mysqli)) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,
                         $db_username,
                         $db_password,
                         $db_name);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_resource($mysqli)` does not report MySQLi resource as valid resource type.

MySQLi uses objects as storage container, not resources; even when
using the procedural API, therefore the output is expected.

This has been [reported as a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42797) a long time ago and it is not a bug, it is expected behavior, as stated by johannes in the comment.

So, I guess, you have to use `mysqli_ping` after all.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods serve a different purposes, therefore a general "this-or-that" answer wouldn't do imo. More likely is "use both".

Two corrections before going on:
1) In your script `$mysqli = new mysqli(...` implies that if valid, $mysqli is an object, not a resource. That's also true if it is created via `$mysqli = mysqli_connect(...`, though it might also be `null` to indicate an error. Use [`$mysqli instanceof MySQLi`](http://docs.php.net/instanceof) to check that, not <strike>is_resource()</strike>.

2) Don't mix mysql_* functions with the MySQLi api. So, it would be [mysql**i**_ping](http://docs.php.net/mysqli.ping) instead of <strike>mysql_ping</strike>.

---

a) Use `$mysqli instanceof MySQLI` to check whether the script got an instance of a mysqli connection, regardless of whether the connection is still usable or not. If $mysqli is not an instance of MySQLi, the script can't use the mysqli_* functions or MySQLi::* methods, including mysqli_ping. When using `$mysqli=mysqli_connect()` instead of `$mysqli = new mysqli(...)` $mysqli might be NULL. instanceof will "return" `false` in that case. Same if $mysqli for some reason is false or a string or a number or ....something else other than an instance of MySQLi.

b) *If* you have an instance of MySQLi, you can use `mysqli_ping($mysqli)` or `$mysqli->ping()` to check whether the connection can still be used or needs to be re-established. There are operations on the MySQLi instance that do work without a valid connection, though those are probably not of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks for the missing "i" and the explanations. Wouldn't `mysqli_ping($mysqli)` simply return false, if there was no instance of `$mysqli`, so that I wouldn't really need to check if the script has an instance of it before I ping?

Comment: If for no other reason, you at least avoid "Warning: mysqli_ping() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given" messages. (And when using the oop interface that would be a fatal error, not a mere warning.)

Comment: I see. In my case the script is run as a cronjob, and errors and warnings get mailed to me. No user sees them. So I guess I'm okay with receiving the warning.

Comment: I'm not going to discuss "but it's only ..." matters, only saying that after a while thinking about "can I get away with this?" takes more brain power than just writing down the cookbook recipe for such boilerplate code.

Comment: On second thought..... that might sound like I'm implying you should always use both ...everywhere. I'm not ;-) I'm just saying: They serve different purposes, use what is appropriate, sometimes both, sometimes neither. E.g. `$mysqli = new mysqli(....); $mysqli->query(....)`. There's no point in testing either instanceof MySQLi or pinging the server. But the code missed to check $mysqli->connect_errno.